# Comments framework for single-page JavaScript MVC application, like Disqus for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, comments, angularjs, singlepage

I am working on single-page AngularJS application that doesn't have any backend but use mongolab for storing data.

It also makes all the calls (like CRUD and filtering) by using the same URL, changing only the part after hashbang (`#`).

So the URL looks like `mysite.com/#!/` for main page, `mysite.com/#!/view/:id` for viewing the story, `mysite.com/#!/edit/:id` for editing it etc.

I would like to use some 3rd party hosted commenting tools to allow users to comment each story. I've tried Disqus and Livefyre, but they're tied to URL before hashbang, so all the website pages is just the single page for them. I've tried to reload Disqus, but it tries to re-attach it's own javascript every time, so loading it multiple times lead to js errors. I have looked at Facebook Comments, but it don't even have a page ID, so the comments are only per site.

Disqus have it's own API, but there are no JS bindings to the newest (and only) version of API (3.0), and creating bindings by myself looks a bit excessively.

Does anyone know good JS comments framework which I could use along with AngularJS or any hosted solution that could help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://docs.angularjs.org/ already do most of what you described here. Disqus works quite well for us. Feel free to look at the source code. Everything is on github.

Comment: Thank you, now I have found a difference. After setting $locationProvider mode to html5, discus start works using the docs.angularjs.org disqusLoad function.